# Find the value of :$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{16\pi D (\Delta t)^3}}e^{-\epsilon^2/(4D(\Delta t))}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is this limit evaluation correct?

$$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{16\pi D (\Delta t)^3}}e^{-\epsilon^2/(4D(\Delta t))} = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{16\pi D (\Delta t)^3 }e^{\epsilon^2/(4D(\Delta t))}}$$

Using L'Hopital's, the numerator is zero: $\frac{d}{dt}\epsilon = 0$ and since the denominator is non zero then the whole limit approaches zero?

If so, then is this also correct:

$$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{3(1-e^{-2\gamma(\Delta t)})^2}{\epsilon^4 \Delta t} = 0$$ ? This second one does not feel right.

Comment: For every positive $a$ and every $b$, $x^be^{a/x}\to+\infty$ when $x\to0^+$. For every $a\ne0$, $1-e^{-ax}\sim ax$ when $x\to0$ hence $(1-e^{-ax})^2/x\sim a^2x\to0$ when $x\to0$. Are these what you are asking?

Comment: I believe so, can you please expand this out a bit in an answer? Thanks!

Comment: No. You should have everything you need to write a nice answer yourself, please do so.

Comment: Rewrite to say $\Delta t \to 0^+.$

Comment: @Did I would, if I knew where this: $(1-e^{-ax})^2/x\sim a^2x\to0$ was coming from

Comment: From the expansion $e^t=1+t+o(t)$ when $t\to0$, naturally.